# Event listener on parent node is triggering on all children nodes too

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, addeventlistener, getelementsbyclassname, stoppropagation

I'm writing a draggable class in vanilla js from scratch (this is NOT related to jQuery draggable), and it's working great, only my listeners are triggering on children of the selected node. I've tried `e.stopPropagation()` inside of the listeners but it doesn't seem to change the outcome.

Here's a snippet of code from the class:

```
setListeners() {

    const targets = document.getElementsByClassName("-jsDraggable");

    [...targets].forEach(elem => {

        elem.addEventListener("mousemove", e => this.handleMouseMove(e));
        elem.addEventListener("mousedown", e => this.handleMouseDown(e));
        elem.addEventListener("mouseup", e => this.handleMouseUp(e));

    });
}
```

... and for example:

```
<ul class="-jsDraggable">
    <li>No drag</li>
    <li>No drag</li>
    <li class="-jsDraggable">Can drag this item</li>
    <li>No drag</li>
</ul>
```

In this scenario I would want both the `<ul class="-jsDraggable">...</ul>` to be affected and also the single `<li class="-jsDraggable">...</li>` inside, where dragging from one of the other list items would simply drag the main `<ul class="-jsDraggable">...</ul>` element.

However, no matter which child node I interact with, regardless of how far down in the DOM it is compared to the node with the class, it triggers the handlers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Another example to clarify:

```
<article class="-jsDraggable">
    <header>
        <h1>Heading</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
        <p>...</p>
    </main>
</article>
```

No matter where I drag in this `<article>` element, it should drag the entire group of HTML as one (since the parent of it all has the class). Currently, however, it's acting more like this:

```
<article class="-jsDraggable">
    <header class="-jsDraggable">
        <h1 class="-jsDraggable">Heading</h1>
    </header>
    <main class="-jsDraggable">
        <p class="-jsDraggable">...</p>
    </main>
</article>
```

... and every single child is also moving when it should only be moving the parent container that has the class attached.

Comment: Stopping event propagation should work. Can you please make a demo of your attempt at using it?

Comment: I think you would want the `mousedown` event to trigger only when `e.target` is a `.-jsDraggable`, otherwise a handler will also trigger when the clicked child is not a `.-jsDraggable`. (not entirely sure what you're wanting to do on mousemove and mouseup, you may or may not want a check there as well) (live snippet would go a long way towards being able to debug the issue)

Comment: I only want the element that contains the class `-jsDraggable` to move, but currently every single node nested within a node with the class is also draggable

Comment: Just stopping the event propagation alone would have it's own problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, it wasn't working because I was setting the current element as `this.elem = e.target` instead of `this.elem = e.currentTarget`. After this, `e.stopPropagation()` in the mousedown worked as expected.

Thanks for exposing me to `e.currentTarget`, I wasn't aware of it before reading the help in this thread.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, then one option (amongst others) is to distinguish the origin of the event, and filter event handling via the `currentTarget` and `target` fields of the `event` object like so:

```
if(event.currentTarget === event.target) {
   /* The user is interacting with the actual -jsDraggable element */
}
else {
   /* The user is interacting with a descendant of a -jsDraggable element */
}
```

This in effect means that, if the element that is spawning the event (ie `currentTarget`) is that same element that the event handler has been bound to (ie `target`), then we determine that the event is in relation to an actual `-jsDraggable` element itself (and not a descendant). This approach compliments your current code as shown:

```js
function handleMouseMove(event) {
  if(event.currentTarget === event.target) {
    console.log(Date.now(), 'Mouse move over draggable');
  }
}
function handleMouseDown(event) {
  if(event.currentTarget === event.target) {
    console.log(Date.now(), 'Drag start on draggable');
  }
}
function handleMouseUp(event) {
  if(event.currentTarget === event.target) {
    console.log(Date.now(), 'Drag end on draggable');
  }
}

function setListeners() {

    const targets = document.querySelectorAll(".-jsDraggable");

    targets.forEach(elem => {

        elem.addEventListener("mousemove", e => handleMouseMove(e));
        elem.addEventListener("mousedown", e => handleMouseDown(e));
        elem.addEventListener("mouseup", e => handleMouseUp(e));

    });
}

setListeners();
```

```css
ul {
  padding:1rem;
  background:lightgreen;
}
li {
  padding:1rem;
  background:pink;
}
.-jsDraggable {
  background:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="-jsDraggable">
    <li>No drag</li>
    <li>No drag</li>
    <li class="-jsDraggable">Can drag this item</li>
    <li>No drag</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This does indeed stop the children from triggering, however the parent also does not trigger (nothing happens). The desired effect is that even when interacting with a child node, if the parent node has the class, it should trigger functionality for the parent